# How do i loop over a List or TreeNodeCollection bacward?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
for (int i = nodes.Count; i < nodes.Count - 1; i--)
            {
                FindRecursive(nodes[i]);
            }
```

nodes.Count = 48
But it's never get in to the FindRecursive(nodes[i]);

Comment: your loop is never get started

Comment: Your loop currently looks like this: for (int i = 48; i < 47; i--). The loop can never start like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition for starting the loop is incorrect. It should be:

```
for (int i = nodes.Count -1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    FindRecursive(nodes[i]);
}
```

In your code `i` starts at `nodes.Count` (`48`). The loop then runs while `i < nodes.Count - 1` but `nodes.Count - 1` can never be greater than `nodes.Count`. You want to stop the loop when you get to the last and as you are going backwards that is element `0`.

**Edit**

Users Default and Yakyb correctly spotted in the code that the starting point is also incorrect.

`nodes` is indexed from `0` to `nodes.Count - 1` so the starting point should be `nodes.Count - 1` not `nodes.Count` to prevent an out of bounds exception.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Yakyb. I've updated the answer to point out that error also.

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ extension method `.Reverse()`.

```
foreach (int i in nodes.Reverse()){
  FindRecursive(i);
}
```